# angularjs ui.bootstrap $modal is not working

Tags: angularjs, ui.bootstrap

i'm new in Angularjs and i would like to ask how can i make my $modal work using "ui-bootstrap".

im getting this kind of error in my console.

```
angular.min.js:118 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=%24modalProvider%20%3C-%20%24modal%20%3C-%20myCtrl
at angular.min.js:6
at angular.min.js:43
at Object.d [as get] (angular.min.js:40)
at angular.min.js:43
at d (angular.min.js:40)
at e (angular.min.js:41)
at Object.invoke (angular.min.js:41)
at S.instance (angular.min.js:89)
at p (angular.min.js:65)
at g (angular.min.js:58)

    // my controller
   <script >
    angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('myCtrl', [ '$scope', '$modal',
        function($scope, $modal) {

    }]);
```

my head Tag :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/myAngularApp/css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myAngularApp/css/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myAngularApp/css/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myAngularApp/css/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myAngularApp/css/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myAngularApp/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myAngularApp/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myAngularApp/css/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myAngularApp/css/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You have way too many dependencies. bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js are the same thing (minified or not), and are not needed by ui-bootstrap, whose goal is precisely to replace this jquery-based code. ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js contains everything ui-bootstrap.min.js contains, plus the HTML templates. jquery is not needed either. And you're not telling us which version of ui-bootstrap you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Change `$modal` to `$uibModal`.

```
<script >
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('myCtrl', [ '$scope', '$uibModal',
    function($scope, $uibModal) {

}]);
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oZKxnfq4gPmta1PIkDbn?p=preview)

[Docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)

Comment: still the error exist sir. i edited the question i include the head tag i hope that helps